# Is there a sequence of functions on $\mathbb {R} $ which is uniformly convergent only on compact subsets of $\mathbb {R} $?

Tags: functions, uniform-convergence

Actually am new to this concept of uniform convergence. I have learned a result (Dini's Theorem) which states that if a sequence of continuous real-valued functions $\{\,f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges pointwise and monotonously $\left(\text{ie} \,f_j(x) \leq f_{j+1}(x) \right)$ to a continuous function $f$ on a compact metric space $(K,d)$, then the convergence is uniform.  Now my doubt is, is there a sequence of functions which is uniformly convergent on every compact subsets while non-uniformly convergent on $\mathbb {R} $ itself? Whichever function I try out doesn't fit into my requirement. Can someone help me please?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Partial sums of the Taylor series for $e^x$

Comment: It's not true that every pointwise convergent sequence of functions on a compact metric space is uniformly convergent. A classic counterexample is the sequence $f_n:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ given by $f_n(x)=x^n$. They converge pointwise to the function $g(x)=0$ if $0\le x<1$ and $g(1)=1$. If the convergence were uniform, the limit function would have to be continuous.

Comment: @JackLee Thanks for pointing it out! I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @user8128 Thanks I got It!

Comment: Another example: the sequence $f_n(x) = \frac{x^2}{n}$.

Comment: @shwetha I don't know who taught you that every pointwise convergent sequence of functions on a compact metric space converging to a continuous function is uniformly convergent, but that is not true. For iinstance, define, for each $n\in\mathbb N$, $f_n\colon[0,1]\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ by $f(x)=n^2x-n^3x^2$ if $x\in[0,\frac1n]$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Then $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges poinwise to the null function, but not uniformly.

Comment: $$\forall x\in\mathbb R\quad\forall n\in\mathbb N\quad f_n(x)=\frac{x}n$$

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos Oh am sorry! I just missed out the word continuity. I hope it's true that pointwise limit of continuous functions on compact metric cos continuous.

Comment: @shwetha It is **false**! Didn't you see my example?

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos Sorry again! Now I realise I have completely misunderstood a result I learnt. Thanks for the patient teaching.

Comment: As you can see from Lee Mosher's and Did's examples it is important that $f_n \in C_0 \left(\mathbb{R} \right)$. The title of your thread seems to have the spirit of Arzela's (an acquaintance of Dini or something) Theorem in mind. If you are interested in Arzela's Theorem or become interested in it then I might advise you see my post (I have no shame) here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2346686/171159